# In objective-c on iPhone, I am attempting to use the NSFileManager. I can't figure out what directory it starts out in

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, nsfilemanager

My question is, what directory does the NSFileManager start out in, I am really confused because when I run code to tell me what directory I'm in, it just outputs /. Also I can change directory to /private/var but not into /mobile and /mobile/applications which is where the application is. Bellow is my code.

`NSString *currentpath;`

```
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];

NSLog (@"Current directory is %@", currentpath);

if ([filemgr changeCurrentDirectoryPath: @"/private/var/mobile"] == NO)
    NSLog (@"Cannot change directory.");

currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];

NSLog (@"Current directory is %@", currentpath);
label.text = currentpath;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want an NSFileManager in the directory your application is? If you want to load something from your own app bundle, look at NSBundle. 

You can't change it to /mobile because that's outside your application's sandbox: you're not allowed to read or write from there.

Comment: This app is not for use on the app store. I thought that even though apple won't allow apps on the app store to work outside of the sandbox, if it was for personal use it wouldn't matter. Also the reason I need it is to move png images to various places on my iPhone.

Comment: It's not a policy limitation of App Store - it's a technical limitation of iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the apps on iOS are sandboxed.  That means that they have their own little sandbox to play around in (each app has its own folder).  The "/" represents the root of the app's sandbox folder.  Quoting Amorya a bit, you cannot write to /private/var because then you are invaliding the app's sandbox's requirements (you can't write there, or read).